# How can I open a .sql file as a package file in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have always worked with PL/SQL Developer and TOAD. Because of the unit testing feature available in SQL Developer I'm very interested in using this program instead of the other ones. But I have sort of a stupid problem. The thing is that all the package files are stored as .SQL files and if I try to open one of them SQL Developer opens it as a SQL sheet. Is there any way to change the view to the PL/SQL view so it shows the debug options and stuff?

Comment: maybe what sql*devloper needs to do is support mode-lines like vim ...ie instead of "# vim: set expandtab:"  have "--sql typetype=package"

Answer (score 5):

If you open a file with a `.pks`, `.pkb`, `.pls` or `.plb` extension, then you get the debugger options:

[image]

[According to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/intro.htm#RPTUG41415) you can link a stored procedure to a file, but I'm not entirely clear what that is supposed to do; if I compile from a `.p*` file then the object is created, but if I open the object from the Connections pane then changes still aren't reflected in the file. I'm not sure what they mean by 'file-based PL/SQL module'...

That doesn't really help you if your file has a `.sql` extension, and that can't be changed (which is likely if it's in source control). You can associate file types, but the built-in ones aren't editable:

[image]

Trying to override that by adding an `extensionsToNodeTypes` entry in `product-preferences.xml` doesn't seem to do anything, and probably wouldn't be supported if it did.

So unless you can change your file extension, I don't think you can do what you're attempting.

Answer (score 3):

If the package in the `.sql` file doesn't exist yet, you can execute the script from the SQL Worksheet (with the 'Run script' button, or with F5).

Once the package exists you can view it; from the Connections pane on the left, expand your current connection to see al the object types, then expand 'Packages' and you'll see your package name. Double click that to open the package specification; and in the Connection pane you'll see that expand so you can see the body, which you can also double-click to view (or there's an 'open body' button at the top of the specification view). Both of those gives you options to execute a procedure/function, debug it, or recompile for debug, etc.

[image]

However, if you change the package through this interface, those changes will not be reflected in your `.sql` file. I have no idea if PL/SQL Developer or Toad link them, but as far as I'm aware there is no way to do that in SQL Developer. It sounds like your `.sql` files are the master at the moment, and presumably under source control, which is good; but you'll need to be aware of that if you start making changes to the package code from this interface.

Comment: I was afraid it couldn't be done with SQL Developer. I really appreciate your effort but that's not an option for me. Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: Oracle really sucks when making user interfaces.